# Array of Buttons in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have defined my buttons in the .xaml.

In the MainPage.xaml.cs I am trying to put them in an array.

```
myButtons[]={But_1,But_2,But_n....};
```

I get the following error.

```
A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'NoteTrainer_.MainPage.But_1'
```

If i put that array in the MainPage() constructor I get no errors,but then I cannot access the array from my methods.

Kinda new to C# and Windows-Phone

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to do, because Button arrays sound very VB6ish to me, and we might be able to guide you toward a better solution.

Comment: I am making a quiz.I am setting a button equal to the button in the array for example correctButton = myButtons[1].I have tried putting that array everywhere loaded,initializing etc.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start with that declaration looks wrong. But for a second thing, the compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong - you're trying to refer to one field within the initializer of another. Put the declaration as normal:

```
Button[] myButtons;
```

and then in the *constructor* you can use:

```
myButtons = new[] { But_1, But_2, ... };
```